# If rules over columns via SQL (Excelstyle)

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

in Excel it's possible to write rules which allows the following calculation:

Wenn means If 
[image: "Wenn means If"]

So basically I calculate if a month (1-12) was used (in this case there is a number). So in February there was a number (1,44) that means a *0* in not used. Tricky is that i also want to calculate if there are a few month not used in a row. So July has to be 3 because column 5,6,7 were not used.
Is there a way to do so in SQL?

**Edit**

There is only on table right now. Auftr_Nr|1|2|3 etc... What I need is a select over this table and add 12 columns for not used. In this table I want to store the values.

Comment: You want your table to permanently to store those values as extra columns - so they'll have to be updated whenever any other data in that row changes? (Which could be make easier with virtual columns, but still messy). Or do you just need them as part of a query; or potentially in a view? This would be simpler if there was one row per month but it doesn't look like that is an option.

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of recursive query, below is working example.

```
/*
with t(autr_nr, c01, c02, c03, c04, c05, c06, c07, c08, c09, c10, c11, c12) as (
    select 10, 0, 1.44, 0, 1.392, 0, 0, 0, 1.406, 1.373, null, null, null from dual 
    union all
    select 20, 7, 9.97, 0, 0, 0, 1.892, 0, 5.406, 2.792, null, null, null from dual ),
*/
with unp as (
    select rownum rn, autr_nr, col, val 
      from t unpivot include nulls (val for col in 
        (c01, c02, c03, c04, c05, c06, c07, c08, c09, c10, c11, c12))),
cte (rn, autr_nr, col, val, nu) as (
    select rn, autr_nr, col, val, 
           case when val = 0 then 1 else 0 end 
      from unp where col = 'C01'
    union all    
    select unp.rn, unp.autr_nr, unp.col, unp.val, 
           case when unp.val = 0 then cte.nu + 1 else 0 end 
      from cte join unp on unp.autr_nr = cte.autr_nr and unp.rn = cte.rn + 1
)
select * 
  from (select autr_nr, col, nu from cte) 
  pivot (max(nu) for col in ('C01', 'C02', 'C03', 'C04', 'C05', 'C06', 
                             'C07', 'C08', 'C09', 'C10', 'C11', 'C12'))
  order by autr_nr
```

**<sup>[demo](http://rextester.com/XSSBC51247)</sup>**

Subquery `t` mimicks your data (I did it to have some input to work with, it's commented, you don't need it in your enviroment), `unp` unpivots rows to columns, recursive `cte` builds counter of continuous zeros, last query changes rows to columns. 
As alternative of `cte` you could use cumulative sum (analytic function).

Result:

```
AUTR_NR 'C01' 'C02' 'C03' 'C04' 'C05' 'C06' 'C07' 'C08' 'C09' 'C10' 'C11' 'C12'
------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- 
     10     1     0     1     0     1     2     3     0     0     0     0     0
     20     0     0     1     2     3     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Not unlike @PonderStibbon's approach, but not recursive:

```
-- CTE just to generate your sample data
with your_table (auftr_nr, "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12") as (
  select 10, 0, 1.440, 0, 1.392, 0, 0, 0, 1.406, 1.373, null, null, null from dual
)
-- end of CTE
select auftr_nr,
  "1_ORG", "2_ORG", "3_ORG", "4_ORG", "5_ORG", "6_ORG", "7_ORG", "8_ORG", "9_ORG", "10_ORG", "11_ORG", "12_ORG",
  "1_NEW", "2_NEW", "3_NEW", "4_NEW", "5_NEW", "6_NEW", "7_NEW", "8_NEW", "9_NEW", "10_NEW", "11_NEW", "12_NEW"
from (
    select auftr_nr, month, org,
      case
        when org is null then null
        when org = 0 then
          month - nvl(max(case when org != 0 then month end)
              over (partition by auftr_nr order by month), 0)
        else 0
        end as new
    from (
      select *
      from your_table
      unpivot (org for month in ("1" as 1, "2" as 2, "3" as 3, "4" as 4, "5" as 5, "6" as 6,
        "7" as 7, "8" as 8, "9" as 9, "10" as 10, "11" as 11, "12" as 12))
    )
)
pivot (sum(org) as org, sum(new) as new for (month) in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12));

  AUFTR_NR      1_ORG      2_ORG      3_ORG      4_ORG      5_ORG      6_ORG      7_ORG      8_ORG      9_ORG     10_ORG     11_ORG     12_ORG      1_NEW      2_NEW      3_NEW      4_NEW      5_NEW      6_NEW      7_NEW      8_NEW      9_NEW     10_NEW     11_NEW     12_NEW
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10          0       1.44          0      1.392          0          0          0      1.406      1.373                                           1          0          1          0          1          2          3          0          0
```

This is taking the row from your original table, unpivoting it to make one row per month, using an analytic function to find the new value you want for each month (which Mr Stibbons referred to), and then pivoting it all back to a single row.

You could potentially create a view over that query so you don't have to add (and maintain) the extra derived values in the actual table.

If you did want those columns it would be quite messy; each one could be a virtual column that looks at its own value and those of all 'earlier' columns, which means they get progressively more complicated. For the first calculated column it would be quite simple, something like:

```
case
  when "1" is null then null
  when "1" = 0 then 1
  else 0
end
```

but the second would extend that:

```
case
  when "2" is null then null
  when "2" = 0 then 1 + 
    case
      when "1" = 0 then 1
      else 0
    end
end
```

and the third:

```
case
  when "3" is null then null
  when "3" = 0 then 1 + 
    case
      when "2" = 0 then 1 +
        case
          when "1" = 0 then 1
          else 0
        end
      else 0
    end
  end
```

and so on, so you can see that by the twelfth column it would be rather long, making the whole thing rather hard to maintain. A view might be a lot easier to maintain - you might need to compare the cost of both approaches though.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I thought already about such a solution, but thought a more easy and effort less way is possible...